# Get deeper evaluation in jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I have python function for jinja, which resturns a string containing jinja instructions, like this:

```
def test():
    # stuff ...
    return "The value of x is {{x}}"
```

I set this function into the global context of jinja, and now I want to use it:

```
{% set x = 3 %}
{{ test() }}
```

Unfortunately, the return value of "test" is not evaluated, so the result is:

```
The value of x is {{x}}
```

Can I somehow force the evaluation of the result of `test`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off using a [jinja2 macro](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#macros).  In this case, you would probably pass `x` to the macro:

```
{% macro test(x) -%}
The value of x is {{x}}
{%- endmacro %}

{% set x = 3 %}
{{ test(x) }}
```

Note that I've passed `x` to the macro -- There really isn't a good reason to not pass `x` and it makes things more clear.  Plus, I'm not even sure how to get it to pass the global variable implicitly ;-).

---

An alternate strategy (which I don't recommend due to decreased clarity and increased risk of messing something up) would be to render a template within your callback function:

```
from jinja2 import Template
def test(x):
    return Template('The value of x is {{x}}').render(x=x)
```

Here I've still passed `x` to the context of the template.  AFAIK, there is no way for the template to pick up the global context within the function (indeed, that would lead to very confusing code).  If you do render a template within the `test` function, you'll have to be careful not to accidentally escape content twice if you're using `autoescape=True`.

Comment: For completness of macro and string templating, a filter could also be used with code like {{ x|test }} and def test(value): return "The value of x if {}".format(value). (but as the answer is from 2016, I hope the asker has go deeper in Jinja documentation since that time)